# Rune Ciphertext (Presumably multi-enciphered )

Tags: cipher, sequence, mechanical-puzzles, symbols

Here is a cryptogram:

Note: this is not, very very hard. But still, it is not very very easy, I would want to say with a few clues it's more easy than hard:
Clues:

- It can be simple substitution.
- It is not enciphered only 1 time.
- It can be made into a mechanical device, with rotors and rings.
- This is not any version of Enigma. (no 'trick' word here, I mean it)

Ciphertext: `ᚣᛖᛒᚢ ᚢᚣᛠᚻᛗ ᛂᛏᚻᛖᛠᚩᚷᛂ ᚢᛒᚣᛂ ᛒᚢ ᚾᛂᚢᚣ`

**2 parts** of the plaintext: `STACK EXCHANGE`

Comment: This is my first post on Puzzling stack exchange! Please, if somethings unclear; tell me that; or if something similar (I don't think?) have been posted here before, (I have used quite unique ways of enciphering the text)

Comment: Usually it's recommended to place hints one every 24 hours or so. Nice puzzle though :)

Comment: @matt thanks! ill keep that in mind next time;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a substitution of

> ᚣ t
>  ᛖ h
>  ᛒ i
>  ᚢ s
>  ᛠ a
>  ᚻ c
>  ᛗ k
>  ᛂ e
>  ᛏ x 
>  ᚩ n
>  ᚷ g
>  ᚾ b

The text becomes

> this stackexchange site is best

No idea what the other step is supposed to be

Comment: EXTREMELY WELL DONE! I can't accept the answer now (7mins and I can) But GOOD WORK!    Wow..   (Your done, if you asked that)  (It's complete) 100/100! A+!